# Category theory & geometric measure theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

My background is essentially Geometric Measure Theory and its application to partial differential equations (e.g. linear and non-linear hyperbolic conservation laws). These are currently my research interests, too.

> **Q.** Is there any link between these areas (GMT, PDEs) and category theory? Could categories be useful to study, e.g. fine properties of BV functions? Or to understand the concept of entropy solution to a non-linear conservation law?

I have looked for similar questions, but I have not found anything as "explicit" as I want. I am not interested into possible definitions of category theory, nor I am looking for some apologies of this area or of that area (everything is math and deserved to be studied). What I would like to know is if it is possible to frame some "fine" definitions/theorems of the areas I am working in by means of the language of CT.

Comment: Category theory hasn't really penetrated analysis, so I doubt it.

Comment: @HarryGindi, I'd disagree with a blanket claim about the irrelevance of category theory to analysis. I include this in my graduate real analysis course the point that the "correct" topology on spaces of smooth functions is demonstrably not a matter of whim, since it must be a (projective) limit of $C^k$ functions. Even more primitively, the "coarseness" of the product topology is explained by its unequivocal categorical definition. The topology on test functions _must_ be the (strict) colimit topology. So I think the _viewpoint_, if not big theorems, of category theory is very relevant.

Comment: see eg Michal Marvan _A note on the category of partial differential equations_, in Differential geometry and its applications, Proceedings of the Conference August 24-30, 1986, Brno  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/MarvanJetComonad.pdf for something on the PDE side, it might be interesting to push this in the direction of geometric measure theory.

Comment: @HarryGindi may not have penetrated to the extent it has algebraic geometry, but that is not to say that it hasn't got some underappreciated connections.

Comment: My bet is that category theory will not help you  with your hyperbolic equations.

Comment: @paulgarrett Sure, category theory is useful most places where you're dealing with multiple interacting structures or natural equipment of constructions with structures that make them universal. I just think that also somehow the actual hard parts of analysis aren't there but elsewhere.  I heard someone say that a great deal of analysis involves very clever applications of very elementary inequalities, but I'm not an analyst, so I defer to you on this question.

Comment: Which isn't to say I wouldn't be pleased if category theory could be used to solve nontrivial problems in analysis! I've just found that many of the "applications" of CT to analysis end up restating problems in a way thaf makes them no easier to solve (or actually harder).

Comment: Peter Freyd said (probably with tongue in cheek) that perhaps the purpose of category theory is to make that which is trivial, trivially trivial.  To the extent that that's true, of course the *actual* hard parts of any subject will not be solved by category theory; the purpose of category theory is to prevent you from wasting your time on the parts that should be easy but look hard if you don't have the right perspective.

Comment: @MikeShulman I see, thanks for your comment. Actually, this was in some sense the point of my question. I understand that CT cannot be just a wizard or some miracle cure, solving all of (our) problems. I am indeed seeking some new point of view, e.g. on 1st order linear/non linear evolutionary PDEs and I was curious to see if CT could provide one. Maybe some of the results I know about this PDE's area that I consider "hard" are just "trivial", seen from the right perspective. Thanks again for your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to look at the notion of [magnitude](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2016/08/a_survey_of_magnitude.html):

[The magnitude of a metric space: from category theory to geometric measure theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00095) by Tom Leinster and Mark W. Meckes

Comment: Wow, looks interesting, thanks! I need of course some time to digest it. Rather than (what I understand for) Geometric Measure Theory, the paper you mention might be relevant for analysis on metric spaces and e.g. [non smooth differential geometry](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-251-1196). Do you know if something of this kind has ever been done (or tried)? Is it worth? Thanks a lot for your interesting answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know a lot about the area. Reading your question I was just reminded of an n-category post I had seen a few days earlier: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2019/01/on_the_magnitude_function_of_d_3.html All my knowledge comes from following some of the links in that post.

Answer (score 8):

I write this as an answer since it is a bit too long for a comment.

Category theory is being used to investigate  differential equations.   A first entry point is through the concept of D-module.

> M.Kashiwara: *D-Modules and Microlocal Calculus*

Another approach is the one pioneered by Kashiwara in

> M. Kashiwara, T. Kawai,  T. Kimura: *Foundations of Algebraic Analysis*, Princeton University Press,1986

For   applications to global problems I suggest looking at the memoir *Ind-Sheaves* by  M.Kashiwara and P. Schapira.   I have to  warn you that the formalism is heavy and   you will need to know a lot  from  Kashiwara and Schapira's book *Sheaves on Manifolds*.

The approach  in the above references is very different from what you think are the traditional pde-s  and  I do not recommend  giving up your day job to learn  this stuff.

I say this from experience. I am trained in  pde. I spent a year learning about derived categories (see [these notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Verdier-ams.pdf)). While  this helped me understand better  various topological problems,  they did not enhance my understanding of pde-s.  In particular, I don't see how category theory will help you understand the concept of entropy solution.  Probably only physics could.

Comment: Thanks for your (in some sense expected) answer. My feeling is that CT might be potentially useful to (re)formulate (P)DE's in some abstract and neat language, but - as far as I got - it is not suitable to fully understand and detect the structure of solutions. E.g. entropy solutions are particular distributional solutions to a hyp cons law: while distributional solutions are generally infinite, they happen to be unique and to have some fine structure - some kind of BV regularity: I do not see a proper way to cast this in the language of CT, nor I see some kind of usefulness. Thanks.

Comment: Have you look at viscosity solutions?

Comment: Nope. Do you think there is some link between them and CT? I have heard people talking about them in conferences a few times, but mostly in talks about other kind of equations - I never saw them related to Hyp. Cons. Laws (linear or nonlinear). I'll give a look, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you  know this paper . http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v161-n1-p06.pdf

Comment: Ah yes, of course! I know that paper (albeit I have never seriously studied it). I have misunderstood your previous comment and I apologize for that. Actually I thought you were referring to something analogous to [this concept of solution](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9207212.pdf). I realized only now you were referring to viscosity solutions in the sense of Bressan-Bianchini.